# Server 2012 R2 unexpected crash DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, server-crashes, unexpected-shutdown

I've a Windows Server 2012 R2 server which acts as Hyper-V host for multiplice Windows/Linux VMs. Since yesterday the server is offline from one second to another, and will reboot automatically. I found out that this is caused by a bluescreen:

[image]

Yesterday this happens three times:

20:57:26

20:15:29

19:57:17

I did a research and find out that this can maybe an issue with an driver, especially the network adapter, and the Large send offload setting. I had it activated, so I disabled it. After that the server runns stable up to now (near 24 hours). Just now the server crashed again.

So it seems like an software issue, but I can't find out what's causing the problem. I haven't install new software or driver in this month, which may be responsible for those problems. Only Windows Updates a few days ago.

All crashes seems the same issue because the bug check string, code and first parameter are the same. Also the driver is equal.

**What can I do to find and fix the issue?**

Comment: Tt seems that this error come from a hardware error on the ram http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-fix-driverirqlnotlessorequal-ntoskrnlexe/1074e8ef-0a4e-45f3-8bc2-40824a42b301?auth=1 you should try a soft to check your RAM integrity

Comment: I wouldn't trust in the driver output of "BlueScreenView" which is used here. Here is my experience with those tools: https://superuser.com/questions/862361/bluescreen-analyzes-with-whocrashed-bluescreenview-and-windbg-different-resul After that loading the dump file in the windows debugger gives the best results.

Answer (score 1):

When everything is working great and then suddenly you obtain driver exceptions it is either 1) a driver update caused a problem, which is unlikely, or 2) you might consider that the hardware is failing.  If a component is dying then drivers will start throwing exceptions.  Do you have another server you can move the drives into? Alternatively, start switching out components, if possible.